# How can I terminate a process if a second inotify event occurs?

Tags: inotify

```
inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,create --recursive ../orgmode-parse-print | 
while read -r filename event; do
    echo $filename;
    echo $event
    sleep infinity;
done
```

The problem with the above is it 'sleeps' forever and never terminates. How can I terminate or restart the process (essentially the contents of the while loop (including the `sleep`)) if another event occurs?

In other words, do the command, but terminate it (interrupt it I suppose) and start again if a file has been modified.

I'm using `sleep` as an example here - the actual process being run is a long running process.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$ inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,create --recursive dir1/ | \
  ( 
    CNT=0; 
    while read -r filename event; do 
       echo "count: $CNT filename: $filename  event: $event"; ((CNT++)); 
       [ "$CNT" -eq 1 ] && exit; 
    done 
  )
```

#### Example

To start I made a sample directory structure to work with:

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/dir2/dir{3..5}

$ tree dir1/
dir1/
└── dir2
    ├── afile
    ├── dir3
    ├── dir4
    └── dir5

4 directories, 1 file
```

I then ran this to start watching the directory:

```
$ inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,create --recursive dir1/ | ( CNT=0; while read -r filename event; do echo "count: $CNT filename: $filename  event: $event"; ((CNT++)); [ "$CNT" -eq 1 ] && exit; done )
```

I then ran `touch afile` commands in this directory:

```
$ cd dir1/dir2
$ touch afile
$ touch afile
```

These resulted in this output from the `inotifywait`:

```
count: 0 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
```

Once it gets to the 2nd 'event' it exits.

#### Problems and a better solution

One issue with the use of the subshell `(...while ...)` to the pipe is that we do not see the 2nd message from `echo` when the 2nd event occurs. No problem we can simply restructure things like this instead:

```
$ CNT=0; while read -r filename event; do echo "count: $CNT filename: $filename  event: $event"; ((CNT++)); [ "$CNT" -eq 2 ] && break; done < <(inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,create --recursive dir1/)
count: 0 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
count: 1 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
$
```

Expanded:

```
$ CNT=0; \
  while read -r filename event; do \
    echo "count: $CNT filename: $filename  event: $event"; ((CNT++)); \
    [ "$CNT" -eq 2 ] && break; \
  done < <(inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,create --recursive dir1/)
count: 0 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
count: 1 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
$
```

#### With a backgrounded task

If you have a task that's going to block inside the `while ...` loop you can introduce a `trap` to kill it, and then background it to allow the `while ...` loop to process input from the `inotifywait`.

Example:

```
$ cat ./notifier.bash
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT;

CNT=0
while read -r filename event; do
  sleep 1000 &
  echo "count: $CNT filename: $filename  event: $event"; ((CNT++))
  [ "$CNT" -eq 2 ] && break
done < <(inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,create --recursive dir1/)
```

In action:

```
$ ./notifier.bash
count: 0 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
count: 1 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
./notifier.bash: line 1: kill: (30301) - No such process
```

And there's no remnants of the backgrounded `sleep` procs:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep [s]leep
$
```

Once last adjustment regarding the `trap` that you may have noticed. When we do that `kill $(jobs -p)` it throws garbage to the screen like this, sometimes:

> ```
> ./notifier.bash: line 1: kill: (30301) - No such process
> ```

We can clean this up like this:

```
 trap 'kill $(jobs -p) > /dev/null 2>&1' EXIT;
```

Now when we run it:

```
$ ./notifier.bash
count: 0 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
count: 1 filename: dir1/dir2/  event: CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE afile
$
```

#### References

- [How do I kill background processes / jobs when my shell script exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I explained it well. The problem with this solution is it won't terminate if the 'command' (sleep for example) is a long running command. Unless I have misunderstood?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski - If you background your long running task this should do it, but yes please update your question, it's not very clear with what you really want then.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski - see latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you just want to terminate whatever your code is doing when a new interruption is received the following bash script works fine for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_function () {
   sleep infinity
}

declare -A cache
inotifywait -q -m -e close_write,create --recursive ../orgmode-parse-print |
while read -r filename event; do
    if [ "${cache[pid_my_function]}" ]; then kill "${cache[pid_my_function]}"; fi
    echo $filename
    echo $event
    my_function &
    cache[pid_my_function]=$!
done
```

Basically, the script puts the long process (that's represented by `sleep infinity`) inside a function, so it can run as an independent process when the function with `&` is called. The command `$!` prints the process number inside a variable so it can be killed later when a new interruption arrives...

---

OBS: This script is killing what your code is doing when a new interruption is received, but I'm not sure if you really want to do that. You could just run each interruption call as a separated process using a function with `&` instead, without necessarily killing the process, so you'd be sure that your script is executed on all interruptions...